# Types of maps in Interpretable Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, explainable-ai, interpretation

I have worked on Interpretable Machine Learning (IML) for over 1 year. However, there are some terminologies that always make me confused.

For example, saliency maps/heat maps. Are they same?

Are activation maps visualizations of activation values of a unit(s) in Neural networks? Do you know any other types of maps?

Thank you.

Comment: another type of map: evidence/against map from Prediction Difference Analysis paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Difference between saliency and heat maps - https://www.reddit.com/r/EyeTracking/comments/hhy2u5/what_is_the_difference_between_saliency_maps_and/
2. Activation maps - https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Feature_maps_(Activation_maps)

These two links should answer your question!

Regarding types of maps, they could be many but activation maps are the most used. People can create various maps so i will not be stressing on the question. I am no expert but I have written one paper on iml. Smoothed Score-CAM. Do look into it :)